What materials are industrially useful, stored in barrels, and explosive?
I'm making a universe where game tropes are justified. One of them is exploding barrels. In many videogames, there are red barrels that explode when shot. Bad guys stand next to these barrels because they have a death wish.
I'm searching for materials that would make sense to store in a barrel, would be common in industrial environments (e.g. factories or warehouses), and, of course, explode when shot with a gun. What substances fit this criteria?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Le salaire de la peur (The Wages of Fear) (1953) by Henri-Georges Clouzot, with Yves Montand. Palme d'Or at Cannes, Golden Bear at Berlin, immortal fame everywhere. Remade three times in America, they say, although in my opinion the original is already perfect.

Specifically (a) what gun (since all guns are not by any stretch of the imagination made equal), (b) how many bullets from that gun and (c) at what range?

I agree that "how does my world generate circumstances in which people commonly store explosives in red barrels in factories and warehouses?" would be a much better question with more interesting and useful answers.

Also... (d) How much damage is expected to occur to someone? (e) How far away are they standing from the barrel? (f) Are they expected to be armored (flak jackets/vests) or unarmored?

A raw material for plastic manufacturing isn't quite explosive as such, but extremely flammable, and is often obtained and stored in barrels when used in medium quantities.  That material is styrene.  Note, this is not polystyrene commonly used for plastic scale models, foam packing material and insulation, and so forth; this is the liquid feedstock that is polymerized to make polystyrene.
In some ways it's more flammable than gasoline, and quite difficult to extinguish.  If the barrel is shot and punctured, the contents (tempoarily pressurized by the shock waves from a supersonic round) will blast from the holes and almost certainly ignite due to the friction heating from the bullet's (or buckshot's) passage, and act enough like an explosion to be satisfying.
Enemies may stand near the barrels while trying to pepper the hero because they're unaware of the hazard, or even just weren't briefed on what's in the barrels (and don't have time to read the hazmat placards and SDS).
Another material in this category that's actually a high explosive is nitromethane.  It's sometimes stored in barrels when used as a feedstock or stored at speed shops (its most common use is as an additive to alcohol fuel for dragsters and old style model airplane engines).  It's liquid, highly flammable, and can detonate -- though you'd need a detonator to actually initiate it into a high order detonation.  It is sufficiently self-oxidizing that an incendiary bullet that penetrates a barrel of the stuff might cause a deflagration, which would still be an explosion (just not one that will shatter concrete walls at several feet distance).

Nitrogen rich Fertilizer: Ammonium Nitrate 
While Im not sure it is stored directly in barrels, Ammonium Nitrate is responsible for the most catastrophic factory and warehouse explosions recorded like the ones in Beirut and Texas.
A powerful and hot enough round can definitely set it off:

While ammonium nitrate is stable at ambient temperature and pressure under many conditions, it may detonate from a strong initiation charge. It should not be stored near high explosives or blasting agents.

From the wiki regarding the Beirut explosion:

The blast was so powerful that it was felt throughout Lebanon. It was also felt in Turkey, Syria, Palestine, Jordan, Israel, and parts of Europe, and was heard in Cyprus, more than 240 km (150 mi) away. It was detected by the United States Geological Survey as a seismic event of magnitude 3.3 and is considered one of the most powerful non-nuclear explosions on record. It was powerful enough to affect Earth's ionosphere.13 The blast was also the largest single-fired ammonium nitrate explosion in history.[4]


Note that Ammonium Nitrate fertilizer might not explode if shot by small and/or slow handgun rounds.

Acetone peroxide
Acetone peroxide is very shock sensitive and has a variety of industrial uses (such as bleaching flour, or as a byproduct of producing plastic).
It usually isn't stored in barrels for safety reasons. If the villain chooses to do so anyways, they should avoid telling their henchmen to avoid legal trouble.

"Acetone peroxide (also called APEX and mother of Satan)" wikipedia definitely agrees

Unless you're postulating some kind of phononic dampening field the bullet could disable, there's no way people are messing around with whole barrels of organic peroxides for any sane purpose.  You'd have to want to blow yourself up.  Most people are afraid to open an old bottle of ether... in case there are traces of peroxides.

@MikeSerfas maybe it is slightly diluted (but not diluted enough to prevent bullets from exploding it). Also, keep in mind that the villain is probably evil.

If you would be willing to accept gas cylinders instead of barrels, then the common-or-garden oxygen and acetylene cylinders used by oxy-acetylene welders would make for exquisitely temperamental barrel-ish metal objects of which the presence in just about any random place would be completely unremarkable.
Perhaps suprisingly, the most common accidents are caused not by the explosive acetylene, but by the high pressure oxygen tank. In the neutral tone of Wikipedia,

Fuel and oxygen tanks should be fastened securely and upright to a wall, post, or portable cart. An oxygen tank is especially dangerous because the gas is stored at a pressure of 21 MPa (3,000 psi; 210 atm)) when full. If the tank falls over and damages the valve, the tank can be jettisoned by the compressed oxygen escaping the cylinder at high speed. Tanks in this state are capable of breaking through a brick wall.

Moreover, the escaping pure oxygen will automatically set on fire random rag soaked with gasoline or grease and so on.
On the other hand, if something goes wrong and the actylene is triggered, the explosion will be stupendous. Just search for oxyacetylene accidents.

I witnessed a small oxy tank fall over and break its valve. It sounded like a shotgun blast went off next to my ear. But you'd need a 50cal or an armor piercing round to punch a hole through one of those tanks.

But you don't need to punch a hole. They already have a hole. All you need to do is to blow off the valve at the top of the tank, either directly or by breaking a support.

From a video game perspective (but not a worldbuilding perspective) that would be way cool! Rather than the ubiquitous exploding barrel, the valves blow (big bang!), gas gushes forth, the tanks fall/spin, then then they magically (who cares, right?) explode. I don't think I've seen that in a shooter before. Yeah, that'd be cool.

We had a cinderblock wall in the metal shop at my college that had an O2 tank go through it... so yeah, those things are every bit as dangerous as advertised.

@JBH, I couldn't tell you which game, but I'm quite sure I have seen that (pressurized canisters shooting around before reaching the point of explosion) done.

@JBH - apologies, deleted

Nitrocellulose is used both as a lacquer component and as a firearm propellant.
It's usually stored wetted with ethanol, so it wouldn't explode, but it's possible that safety precautions weren't followed, or the factory is abandoned, so it dried out.
